# Autocomplete with multiple datasets in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have a working autocomplete which is similar to this `jsfiddle` 
but for my autocomplete I want it to have multiple datasets similar to the [twitter typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#multiple-datasets) but I don't know if it is possible to get multiple datasets autocomplete using bootstrap autocomplete and if yes, can someone let me know how can I do that and if no, then can any of you tell me how should I implement  twitter multiple datasets typeahead in my application. Thank You.

Here is the jsfiddle [link.](http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have an ajax call populating these datasets, thus am using timeout here to simulate an ajax promise. This is how I would do what you are asking:

```
    function myService($timeout) {
            var data1 = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"],
                data2 = [ 'xx','xxx','xxxx'];
            return {
                returnData : function() {
                   return $timeout(function() {},200).then(function() {
                        return [].concat(data1,data2);
                });
            }
      }
    }

    function DefaultCtrl($scope, myService) {
        myService().then(function(response) {
                $scope.names = response;
        });
    }
```